# Retrieve and display multiple and different mysql queries using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have several div tags that I would like to be updated with several different mysql queries.

My code below only updates one of these divs, how can I expand it to 1-6 and also leave room for expansion in the future for more divs?

I also need to be able to update each div individually with a specific query for a specific table.

```
<html>

<div id="1"> </div>
<div id="2"> </div>
<div id="3"> </div>
<div id="4"> </div>
<div id="5"> </div>
<div id="6"> </div>
//...and so on

</html>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
function display($id) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "apifile.php",
        data: {id:$id},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            if(msg.success) {
                $($id).next(".one").html(msg);
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

---

```
<?php

mysql_connect(host, user, pass);
mysql_select_db(name);
mysql_query("select round((count(*)*100)/(select count(*) from test),1) as percent from test group by field1 order by percent desc");

$reply['success'] = "Success"; 
if($return = display($id)) {
    $reply['success'] = "Success";
} else {
    $reply['error'] = "Error";
}
echo json_encode($reply);

?>
```

Comment: Why not just make one Ajax call and return an array of the data you need? (given its the Se database) Then you can just loop through that array with jQuery printing the DIVs and the data as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store the data/messages/otherinfo from each query in different portions of your $reply array

```
query1 goes here ...

   $reply[1]['success'] = "Success"; 
if($return = display($id)) {
    $reply[1]['success'] = "Success";
} else {
    $reply[1]['error'] = "Error";
}

query2 goes here ...

$reply[2]['success'] = "Success"; 
$reply[2]['data'] = "3,4,5"; 

query3 goes here ...

$reply[3]['success'] = "Success"; 
$reply[3]['data'] = "beans,soup,guac"; 

echo json_encode($reply);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the div and run the ajax on class

```
$( ".div" ).each(function() {
    var div_id = $(this).attr('id');
    display(div_id);
});
```